# How do i Select 2 different things - Regex

Tags: regex

How would I select everything after the Last underscore of a file name and everything between the second to last and the last underscore?

Example file name,

```
12345A_NameHere_FRONT_3_10
```

All i am able to do at the moment is select whats after the last underscore.

```
.*_(.*)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `[^_]*` instead of `.*` to match sequences of non-underscores. Then anchor it to the end so you get the last two blocks.

```
([^_]*)_([^_]*)$
```

Capture group 1 contains everything between the 2nd-to-last and last underscore, capture group 2 contains everything after the last underscore.

Comment: Thanks so much,  How would i select just what is between the Last and Second to last underscores?

Comment: Get rid of the second capture group. The first capture group gets that.

Comment: When I do this it select the 10 and not the 3.   ([^_]*)$

Comment: It works here: https://regex101.com/r/KdO11C/1

Comment: I suspect you got rid of all of `_([^_]*)` rather than just removing the `()` around it.

Comment: ([^_]*)_[^_]*$ is capturing everything before the last underscore when i run it.

Comment: I can't think of any reason for that, unless the filename contains Unicode characters that look like underscore, but aren't the same character.

Comment: Maybe the Esko software that this is running through does that.

Comment: I figured it out!  (?<=_)[^_]+(?=_[^_]+$)

Comment: The difference is that this doesn't require accessing the captured groups.